# Show read and not readed notifications

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, mariadb

I'm developing a custom notifications system with PHP and MariaDB. I'm struggling with the "read notification" logic.

This is my `notifications` table:

```
|id | title       | content       | uid        | visibility | timestamp |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|11 | Other title | Other content | sz46j86rd  | public     | 0123456789 |
|10 | My title    | My content    | xrgoyyzm27 | private    | 0123456789 |
... And so on ...
```

And this is my `notifications_viewed` table:

```
| id | user_id | notification_uid | timestamp  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2  | 1       | xrgoyyzm27       | 1234567890 |
```

So, what I need is retrieve from the database the notifications and check if that notification has been viewed/readed by the current user.

I'm already showing the notifications (that works just fine) but I don't know how to check if each of the last 5 notifications that I show in the topbar dropdown has been seen/view/read by the current user. Maybe some kinf of SQL `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT n.*, IF(nv.id IS NULL, 'No', 'Yes') AS viewed
FROM notifications AS n
LEFT JOIN notifications_viewed AS nv ON n.uid = nv.notification_uid AND nv.user_id = :current_user
```

BTW, foreign keys usually refer to the primary key of the parent table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why `IF(nv.id IS NULL [...]`? I tried that query but it throws the same info as `SELECT * FROM notifications` would do.

Comment: When there's no matching row in the `notifications_viewed` table, all the columns from that table will be `NULL` in the join. This is a standard SQL pattern.

Comment: Roger that. So, I tried again that query and is now working as expected?? That's weird, I tried 5 mins ago and didn't show the "viewed" column.

Comment: Maybe the `nv.user_id`. So, yeah, now is working fine! Thanks again for your time :)